# copy value from one field to another

Tags: javascript, copy, field

I have found this fiddle (cannot remember the source):
http://jsfiddle.net/FPsdy/1/
which does exactly what I want (copy contents from a field to another)

When I copy it into a php page, though, it doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    $('#elm_14').val($('#elm_6').val());
    $('#elm_16').val($('#elm_7').val());
});
</script>

<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[firstname]" id="elm_6">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[lastname]" id="elm_7"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Continue" name="dispatch[checkout.update_steps]"><br />
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[b_firstname]" id="elm_14">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[s_firstname]" id="elm_16">

</body>
</html>
```

I am sure I have made an amateur mistake but, since I do not know javascript I cannot pinpoint it. Any help is well appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your js code that attaches the click handler needs to be run AFTER the page loads:

```
$(function() { // is run after DOM is completely loaded
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
        $('#elm_14').val($('#elm_6').val());
        $('#elm_16').val($('#elm_7').val());
    });
});
```

In your code, when the JS is run, the submit button doesn't exist yet on the page, so jQuery can't attach the click handler.